# Grant permission for publishing options without full 'administer content' permission

Tags: 7, users, nodes

As the question says. I'm working on a news site, and authors should be able to create a full piece and be able to chose whether to publish or not. How can you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Save Draft](http://drupal.org/project/save_draft) module. It adds a 'Save as Draft' Button to the node_form for content types, allowing the user to click the 'Save as Draft' button to save the node as a draft. It has it own separate permissions aside from the 'administer content' core permission.

Comment: Good suggestion. 'Save Draft' seems to just make a node 'unpublished'.. or at least views sees it that way. Great!

Comment: Yes. it's just a nice little UX tweak for everyday use, so users don't have to go hunting for the published checkbox. It just also happens to provide it's own separate permissions which is useful in your use case.

Answer (score 3):

The [Publish Content](http://drupal.org/project/publishcontent) module could be useful.